# How to retrieve array of specific field of sub document- mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my first mongodb project,I have this document structure in mongodb, I am trying to retrieve a particular user account (each user account has an array of contacts), from this user account, I will then obtain an array of the ID fields of the users contacts and then pass this array as a parameter to another query, I am doing this to avoid having to loop through the users contacts array in order to obtain the ID fields, here is the document structure, the query I tried is below it

```
{
  name,
  id,

  contacts:[{
             contactId, //I need an array of this field
             dateAdded
             },
             contactId,
             dateAdded
             },
              {}..]
}

//
  var findByIdAll = function(accountId, callback) {
     var self=this;
          //Get the user account
      Account.findOne({_id:accountId}, function(err,doc) {

          /  After the user account has been obtained, the function below will
        // use an array of the users contactsId's to fetch the contact's accounts
          //please how do I obtain the array of contact Id's before reaching here                     

       self.Account.find({_id:{$in:[/array of contact Ids]}},function(err,results){
      callback(results);
    });
    });
  };
```

EDIT
//I have now been able to obtain an array of contactID fields using the following query

```
 var r=db.accounts.aggregate({$match:{email:'m@live.com'}},{$unwind:"$contacts"},
       {$project:{_id:0,contacts:1}},{$group:{_id:'$_id',
       list:{$push:'$contacts.accountId'}}});

    The result I get from the query is
```

> r

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : null,
                        "list" : [
                                ObjectId("51c59a31c398c40c22000004"),
                                ObjectId("51c59a31c398c40c22000004")
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A normal MongoDB query will always give you the entire document with the same structure.
If you want to get just part of the document or make a transformation to it you need to use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) (is not as hard to understand as it looks, give it a try).

In your case you might have to use [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in contacts to explode the array, [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to get only the account you want, and [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to present the data as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I am not getting the desired output, the unwind produces an array of objects each with the projected fields of the parent document and an index of the subdocument

Comment: Here is what I have tried    db.accounts.aggregate({$match:{email:'m@live.com'}},{$unwind:"$contacts"
,{$project:{accountId:1}});

Comment: when I use project, it only works on the parent document and not on the subdocument

Comment: In $project, you have to specify all the fields you want to be returned. It's like when you do `SELECT field1, field2 +1 AS newField FROM....` Try including contacts

Comment: I am getting contacts but is it possible to project only the Id field of contact and place these ID fields in an array using the aggregate methods? cuz it seems project affects the parent document, but for the subdocument (contacts) it returns all fields thanks

Comment: I don't think the aggregation methods can create an array with the output (if so, it would be in $project). But you can make $project return only the Id's; that will give you a list (would be a List<String> in java) which can be converted into an array without iterate it.

Comment: Try something like `{$project:{_Id:0,contactId:1}}`. How about if you update the question with your query with aggregation and the output? That could be helpful

Comment: Thanks am getting this result now, a list of contacIds, looks like this   [ ObjectId<xxxxxx>,ObjectId<cccccc>] but still trying to convert it to a pure array

Comment: Isn't `[ ObjectId<xxxxxx>,ObjectId<cccccc>]` an array of ObjectId's? I think you can pass that result to your query: `{_id:{$in:[/array of contact Ids]}}`

Comment: Great! If you feel my answer helped you enough to mark it as the correct answer please do so.  Thanks